# Merge duplicated values in array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like this

```
arr_of_hashes = [
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-11", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-11"},
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-13", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-13"},
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-13", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-13"}, 
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-16"},
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-16"},
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"still active"}
]
```

I want to remove duplicates. Also, among:

```
{"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-16"},
{"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"still active"}
```

I want to keep only the last line. How can I do that?

I tried to do:

```
sorted_arr = arr_of_hashes.uniq
```

Comment: The issue is entirely not clear. You haven't explained at all why you only want to keep the last one among `{"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-16"},
 {"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"still active"}`.

Comment: Do you mean that for each group of hashes for which the value of `started_at" is the same you wish to keep only the last element? If not, do you wish to keep only the last element of the group when the value of "stopped_at"` is the particular string `"still active"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr_of_hashes.reverse.uniq { |hash| hash["started_at"] }.reverse
```

About [pass block to `uniq`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq#1380-Pass-a-block) and about [`reverse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse).

```
#result
[
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-11", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-11"},
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-13", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-13"},
  {"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"still active"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
[2] pry(main)> arr_of_hashes.reject { |h| h['started_at'] == h['stopped_at'] }
[
    [0] {
        "started_at" => "2018-07-16",
        "stopped_at" => "still active"
    }
]
```

Its not clear form your question what output you want to get

Answer (score 0):

```
arr_of_hashes.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g["started_at"]=>g) }.values
  #=> [{"started_at"=>"2018-07-11", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-11"},
  #    {"started_at"=>"2018-07-13", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-13"},
  #    {"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"still active"}]
```

See [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) and note that `values`'s receiver is as follows.

```
arr_of_hashes.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g["started_at"]=>g) }
  #=> {"2018-07-11"=>{"started_at"=>"2018-07-11", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-11"},
  #    "2018-07-13"=>{"started_at"=>"2018-07-13", "stopped_at"=>"2018-07-13"},
  #    "2018-07-16"=>{"started_at"=>"2018-07-16", "stopped_at"=>"still active"}}
```